How to remove back of hutch on an desk once cam locks are removed but shafts are on opposite sides of corners
I must remove the back side of a desk hutch built with cam locks. The locks are across the top and down one side which is a corner. I have removed the cam locks, but the cam lock bolt portion in the top corner on the right and left side will not allow me to pull the board away.

This could use a photo and/or a diagram to clarify the problem.

Probably you need to take more than just the part you want off apart, based on the word-description. But clear pictures would help immensely, indeed. i.e. you have to take it apart opposite the way it goes together. So if it was A, then B, then C, you can't get B out without taking C out first.

Pictures of how your back is held on by cam locks will be especially useful as it's usual for the bolts and dowels to hold the sides, top and shelves together and for the back to be a flimsy thing held on some other way.

Classical flatpack for a "desk hutch" as I understand the term would require removing the whole hutch from the top of the desk, straight up vertically. Probably two camlocks in the sides of the desk and a couple of dowels per side.
The back (if a thin sheet of plywood) would be a sliding fit in grooves on the uprights. Though you might be describing a back board actually camlocked into place (showing why pictures would help.) Attempting to disassemble the hutch without lifting it off the desk first will be a  problem. That sounds close enough to your verbal description, until we get pictures.
On similar flatpacks I've dealt with that would be the ONLY disassembly required, if the back comes all the way down to the top of the desk it will stay put while you lift the hutch off, then fall over. They are moderately annoying to get in place correctly due to that. If it's only on the upper part, or is a full-thickness board with camlocks and dowels holding it, you'd have to disassemble further.

Sometimes the back is nailed rather than slotted.  Those are not so easy to remove.
